# How to create multiple database tables on plugin activation?

Tags: plugins, database, sql, activation

I have an activation hook to create 2 new database tables that don't exist, only the second table is created from this code:

```
    public function add_tables() {

        // Global $wpdb

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->hide_errors();

        // Require upgrade

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

        // Set charset

        $collate = '';
        if ( $wpdb->has_cap( 'collation' ) ) {
            $collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
        }

        // SQL query

        $sql = "
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $wpdb->prefix . "test1 (
            test_id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            test_key char(64) NOT NULL,
        ) $collate;
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $wpdb->prefix . "test2 (
            test_id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            test_key char(64) NOT NULL,
        ) $collate;
        ";

        // Do SQL

        dbDelta( $sql );

    }
```

Why only the second? If I print out the `$sql` variable I get the SQL statement and if I run that in phpMyAdmin it creates the 2 tables.

I looked at how plugins like WooCommerce do it (https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/c04f7b79f972ee854e5f5d726eb78ac04a726b32/includes/class-wc-install.php#L687) and it appears I am doing the same as they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why only the second?

Because `dbDelta()` supports `CREATE TABLE table_name` format only. I.e. Exactly "CREATE TABLE" followed by (one space and) the table name.

More specifically, `dbDelta()` uses this regular expression pattern: `CREATE TABLE ([^ ]*)` when parsing the queries into an array indexed by the table name; i.e. `array( 'table_1' => 'query', 'table_2' => 'query', ... )`.

Here's the relevant [code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L2547):

```php
$cqueries   = array(); // Creation Queries
...

// Create a tablename index for an array ($cqueries) of queries
foreach ( $queries as $qry ) {
    if ( preg_match( '|CREATE TABLE ([^ ]*)|', $qry, $matches ) ) {
        $cqueries[ trim( $matches[1], '`' ) ] = $qry;
        $for_update[ $matches[1] ]            = 'Created table ' . $matches[1];
    }
    ...
}
```

So in the case of `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name`, the table name is (seen as) `IF` and not `table_name` due to the regular expression pattern:

```php
preg_match( '|CREATE TABLE ([^ ]*)|', 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name', $matches );
var_dump( $matches );
/* Output:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "CREATE TABLE IF"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "IF"
}
*/

preg_match( '|CREATE TABLE ([^ ]*)|', 'CREATE TABLE table_name', $matches );
var_dump( $matches );
/* Output:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "CREATE TABLE table_name"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "table_name"
}
*/
```

And in your case, both queries do match that pattern, but since the table names are both (seen as) `IF`, the first/previous array item (`$queries['IF']`) is then overridden. Hence only the second table (the one in the final value of `$queries['IF']`) gets created.

And WooCommerce actually do **not** have `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` in their code:

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/c04f7b79f972ee854e5f5d726eb78ac04a726b32/includes/class-wc-install.php#L687

**Possible Solution when using the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name` format**

Call `dbDelta()` for each of the queries, as in @FahamShaikh's answer:

```php
$queries = [ // array of queries
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $wpdb->prefix . "test1 ...",
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $wpdb->prefix . "test2 ...",
];

foreach ( $queries as $sql ) {
    dbDelta( $sql );
}
```

Or:

```php
dbDelta( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $wpdb->prefix . "test1 ..." );

dbDelta( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $wpdb->prefix . "test2 ..." );
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to get it to work would be to do it like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->hide_errors();
// Require upgrade
// Set charset
$collate = '';
if ( $wpdb->has_cap( 'collation' ) ) {
    $collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
}
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
$queries = array();
array_push($queries, "
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}test1 (
       `test_id1` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `test_key1` char(64) NOT NULL,
       `test_key21` char(64) NULL, PRIMARY KEY  (`test_id1`)
    ) {$collate}");
array_push($queries, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}test2 (
        `test_id2` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `test_key2` char(64) NOT NULL,
        `test_key12` char(64) NULL, PRIMARY KEY  (`test_id2`)
    ) {$collate}");
foreach ($queries as $key => $sql) {
    dbDelta( $sql );
}
```

I agree that this doesn't actually explains why the supported format for `dbdelta` is not working but this seems to work at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that worked for me which I found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-multiple-wpdb-tables-during-plugin-installation/):

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

$sql = 'CREATE TABLE table1...';
dbDelta ($sql);

$sql = 'CREATE TABLE table2...';
dbDelta ($sql);

$sql = 'CREATE TABLE table3...';
dbDelta ($sql);
```

Here's how I used it in a plugin:

```
/**
 * register_activation_hook implementation
 */
if (!function_exists('custom_install')) {
    function custom_install()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        global $custom_db_version;

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'customers';

        $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'favorite';

        // sql to create your table
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
            id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            message text,
            amount VARCHAR(255),
            status VARCHAR(10),
            PRIMARY KEY (id)
        );";

        $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name2 . " (
            `color` bigint(12) NOT NULL,
            `size` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);
        dbDelta($sql2);

        // save current database version 
        add_option('custom_db_version', $custom_db_version);
    }

    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'custom_install');
}
```